# Symfony 3 - ('required => true') in FormType doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony

I use VichUploaderBundle to manage files on my site.

I would like in a form to ensure that several attributes are required.

These are attributes of type File, and an attribute of type Entity:

```
    ->add('paquetFile', VichFileType::class, array(
        'required' => 'required',
        'label'=> "Package",
        'allow_delete' => false,
    ))

->add('typeUser',EntityType::class, array(
        'required' => 'required',
        'class'=>'Site\PagesBundle\Entity\TypeUser',
        'choice_label'=>'typeUtilisateur',
        'expanded'=>true,
        'multiple'=>true,
    ));
```

But in the form, it does not work. I can validate without filling these two fields. And of course, since they can not be null, I have an error.
Whereas for a normal attribute of type Text, the constraint works.

How to force the user to choose a file with the File attribute, and force him to check at least one checkbox in the EntityType?

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="urlPaquet", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $urlPaquet;

/**
 * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="paquet", fileNameProperty="urlPaquet")
 * @var File
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $paquetFile;

/**  
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="TypeUser", inversedBy="packages")  
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="Packages_des_TypesUser") 
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */  
private $typeUser;
```

EDIT: For the File, I added "@Assert\NotBlank()" on my entity and it's OK. But for the "typeUser", doesn't work

Thank you !

Comment: try `'required' => 'required' `

Comment: Same problem :/

Comment: You are using `'required'` twice, could you remove one

Comment: `->add('paquetFile', VichFileType::class, array(
        'required' => true,
        'label'=> "Package",
        'required'=>false,
        'allow_delete' => false
    ))`
to 
`->add('paquetFile', VichFileType::class, array(
        'required' => true,
        'label'=> "Package",
        'allow_delete' => false
    ))`

Comment: Oops, I removed the second 'required', but the problem is the same

Comment: I edited my post, I found for the File, but nothing for the EntityType

Comment: `required` is [boolean and by default true](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/forms/types/text.html#required)

Comment: check you in the element is `required` append correctly

Comment: Okay, I removed the 'required' on the FormType. It seems work for File with my "@Assert\NotBlank()" on the entity. But for the EntityType, what should I add on the entity.php ?

Comment: You can use `@Assert\NotNull()` assertion for the EntityType.